# Baixar Série DI do site da BM&F

Tags: html, r, iframe

Eu estou tentando puxar uma série do site da bovespa com o valor do Swap DI nos últimos 10 dias pelo iframe e consolidar em um arquivo. Porém, ao invés das colunas estarem trazendo a cotação do dia indicado, todas as colunas estão vindo com o valor do último dia disponível. Não estou achando o problema.

```
for (lib in c('tidyverse','rvest', 'bizdays', 'dplyr', 'lubridate' , 'openxlsx')){
      if (!lib %in% rownames(installed.packages())){
        lapply(lib, install.packages, character.only = TRUE)
      }
      if (!lib %in% (.packages())){
        lapply(lib, library, character.only = TRUE)
      }
    }
    rm(lib)
    

print(paste(Sys.time(), ": Inicio.",  sep=''))
di360 <- NULL
di252 <- NULL
for (i in c(1:10*1)){

  dt <-format(today()-i, "%d/%m/%Y")
  
  # bovespa <- 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=10/03/2021'
  bovespa <- url('https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp', 'rb')
  
  html <- read_html(bovespa) 
  
  dados_bov <- html %>%
    html_nodes(
      xpath = '//*[@id="tb_principal1"]'
    ) %>%                                   
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace(",", ".") %>%
    str_replace_all('(\r|\n){1,}',';')
  
  if (!is_empty(dados_bov)){
    temp <- NULL
    dados_bov = strsplit(
      dados_bov,';')[[1]][5:length(strsplit(dados_bov,';')[[1]])] %>%              
      matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)%>%
      as.data.frame()%>%
      setNames(c("dc", "DI_pre_252", "DI_pre_360"))
    
    
    temp360 <- dados_bov[, c('dc', 'DI_pre_360')]
    temp360$DI_pre_360 <- gsub(',', '.', temp360$DI_pre_360)
    temp360$DI_pre_360 <- as.numeric(temp360$DI_pre_360)
    temp360$dc <- as.numeric(temp360$dc)
    names(temp360) <- c('dc', dt)

    temp252 <- dados_bov[, c('dc', 'DI_pre_252')]
    temp252$DI_pre_252 <- gsub(',', '.', temp252$DI_pre_252)
    temp252$DI_pre_252 <- as.numeric(temp252$DI_pre_252)
    temp252$dc <- as.numeric(temp252$dc)
    names(temp252) <- c('dc', dt)
    
    if (is.null(di360)){
      di360 <- temp360
      di252 <- temp252
    } else {
      di360 <- full_join(temp360, di360, by = 'dc')
      di252 <- full_join(temp252, di252, by = 'dc')
    }
  }
  print(paste(Sys.time(), ": Dia: ", dt, '.',  sep=''))
}

print(paste(Sys.time(), ": fim.",  sep=''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada iteração estava apagando os dados anteriores, acredito que o código abaixo soluciona o que precisa. Inclui uma coluna com a data da consulta, para evitar nomes diferentes nas colunas.

```
library('rvest')
library('xml2')
library('tidyverse')
library('lubridate')

# library('bizdays')
# library('dplyr')
# library('openxlsx')

di360 <- NULL
di252 <- NULL

for (i in c(1:10*1)){
  
  dt <-format(today()-i, "%d/%m/%Y")
  
  # bovespa <- 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=10/03/2021'
  bovespa <- url('https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp', 'rb')
  
  html <- read_html(bovespa) 
  
  dados_bov <- html %>%
    html_nodes(
      xpath = '//*[@id="tb_principal1"]'
    ) %>%                                   
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace(",", ".") %>%
    str_replace_all('(\r|\n){1,}',';')
  
  if (!is_empty(dados_bov)){
    temp <- NULL
    dados_bov = strsplit(
      dados_bov,';')[[1]][5:length(strsplit(dados_bov,';')[[1]])] %>%              
      matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)%>%
      as.data.frame()%>%
      setNames(c("dc", "DI_pre_252", "DI_pre_360"))
    
    temp360 <- dados_bov[, c('dc', 'DI_pre_360')]
    temp360$DI_pre_360 <- gsub(',', '.', temp360$DI_pre_360)
    temp360$DI_pre_360 <- as.numeric(temp360$DI_pre_360)
    temp360$dc <- as.numeric(temp360$dc)
    temp360$dt <- dt
    
    temp252 <- dados_bov[, c('dc', 'DI_pre_252')]
    temp252$DI_pre_252 <- gsub(',', '.', temp252$DI_pre_252)
    temp252$DI_pre_252 <- as.numeric(temp252$DI_pre_252)
    temp252$dc <- as.numeric(temp252$dc)
    temp252$dt <- dt
    
    di360 <- rbind(di360, temp360)
    di252 <- rbind(di252, temp252)
  }
}

rm(dados_bov, html, tem252,temp360, bovespa,dt,i,temp, temp252)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Valeu demais